# Filling in missing values in a column based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that has 3 columns: `recnum`, `state`, and `zip_code`. The `state` column is missing values and I want to fill them in based on matching `zip_code`. I have tried using `.ffill` with no luck. Below is a sample of how the `df` currently looks and what I want the output to look like. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

recnum: int64
state: string
zip: float64

Current `df`

| recnum | state | zip_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AL | 11111 |
| 2 | CO | 22222 |
| 3 | TX | 33333 |
| 4 | NaN | 11111 |
| 5 | AL | 11111 |
| 6 | CO | 22222 |
| 7 | TX | 33333 |
| 8 | NaN | 22222 |

Desired Output:

| recnum | state | zip_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AL | 11111 |
| 2 | CO | 22222 |
| 3 | TX | 33333 |
| 4 | AL | 11111 |
| 5 | AL | 11111 |
| 6 | CO | 22222 |
| 7 | TX | 33333 |
| 8 | CO | 22222 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping by zip_code then using ffill, bfill to fill out the nans:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'recnum': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8},
                   'state': {0: 'AL', 1: 'CO', 2: 'TX', 3: np.nan, 4: 'AL',
                             5: 'CO', 6: 'TX', 7: np.nan},
                   'zip_code': {0: 11111, 1: 22222, 2: 33333, 3: 11111,
                                4: 11111, 5: 22222, 6: 33333, 7: 22222}})

df['state'] = df.groupby('zip_code')['state'].ffill().bfill()
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   recnum state  zip_code
0       1    AL     11111
1       2    CO     22222
2       3    TX     33333
3       4    AL     11111
4       5    AL     11111
5       6    CO     22222
6       7    TX     33333
7       8    CO     22222
```